# OpenCV - overwriting live video

Tags: python, opencv

I made a convolutional neural network, that predicts faces and returns coordinates (y1, x1, y2, x2). Iam able to create rectangle that serves as mask that covers the desired coordinates. I need a way to cover the images in real time. Is there a way to get live image sequence without saving the frames, just overwriting them, and how do i extract the coordinates in openCV? I was using pyplot and was saving the images, it is slow and ineffective.

Comment: Do you want to modify and render the images in real time?

Comment: Would like to modify them in real time.

Comment: What did you try so far? We can help improving your code but cannot say anything without it. Please edit the post to include a minimal example code.

Comment: Would love to share the code, what I can share is how I get the coordinates in the picture. What I dont know is, how to extract frame from video without saving the image in any file, just in variable, so I can work on the picture without saving it and than assamble the frames into video again.

Comment: Which neural network are you using? After spotting the line in its code where the frames are saved to file, you can grab the numpy array at that point to process without saving.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so I managed to come up with a solution, but I found out that, 1 frame takes about `0.54s` to compute, so `2FPS`, not great for live streaming, so I am switching to `haarcascade`.

Code below is used to configure and call the model.

```
from numpy import expand_dims
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN
from mrcnn.model import mold_image
import cv2
import time



# define the prediction configuration
class PredictionConfig(Config):
    # define the name of the configuration
    NAME = "face_cfg"
    # number of classes (background + face)
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1
    # simplify GPU config
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

def classify_image(image,model,cfg):
    # convert pixel values (e.g. center)
    scaled_image = mold_image(image, cfg)
    # convert image into one sample
    sample = expand_dims(scaled_image, 0)
    # make prediction
    tic = time.time()
    yhat = model.detect(sample, verbose=0)[0]
    print(time.time() - tic)
    return yhat['rois']

def image_bnd_highlight(image,coordinates):
    for box in coordinates:
        # get coordinates
        y1, x1, y2, x2 = box
        # create the shape
        new_img = cv2.rectangle(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),5)
        return new_img

# create config
cfg: PredictionConfig = PredictionConfig()
# define the model
model = MaskRCNN(mode='inference', model_dir='./', config=cfg)
# load model weights
model_path = 'mask_rcnn_face_cfg_0029.h5'
model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True)
definitive_model = model
```

Then I call my functions, that I created above.

```
import cv2 as cv
import acapture
from RealTime import definitive_model
from RealTime import cfg
from RealTime import classify_image
from RealTime import image_bnd_highlight
import time

# cap = acapture.open(0)
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,128) #set frame width
cap.set(4,128) #set frame height
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 2) #adjusting fps to 2
# cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,3)

# if not cap.isOpened():
#     print("Cannot open camera")
#     exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # let's resize our image to be 150 pixels wide, but in order to
    # prevent our resized image from being skewed/distorted, we must
    # first calculate the ratio of the *new* width to the *old* width
    r = 150.0 / frame.shape[1]
    dim = (150, int(frame.shape[0] * r))
    # perform the actual resizing of the image
    resized = cv.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    # tic = time.time()
    coords = classify_image(resized,definitive_model,cfg)
    # print(time.time() - tic)
    image = image_bnd_highlight(resized,coords)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', image)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```